# OK Google voice command through bluetooth headset (D.I.Y. Google Home device)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, nexus-5x

I have a Bluetooth speaker with a built in microphone (and also several bluetooth headsets which are essentially the same). I have it paired with my Nexus 5x running Marshmellow. I would like to have a setup such that when the bluetooth device is on and connected, I can speak "OK Google" into the bluetooth device and Google Now activates on the phone.

[image: ok google]

I am fully aware that I can launch Google Now through a button push on the bluetooth device (albiet the speaker does not have any buttons but power on/off), however, I dont want to have to push any buttons. I want to activate Google Now, through the bluetooth device, hands free.

Note, in the Google Voice settings, I do have "Bluetooth Headset" on and "Hands free for Bluetooth devices" also on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, it works on my Android 4.4 tablet with a Technika bluetooth speaker and I can say "Ok Google" anywhere in the room and it picks it up, it's pretty sweet! just like an Amazon Echo or Google Home device, just free.. haha. Just make sure "Ok Google anywhere" is turned on in the Google app settings and that your mic option is turned on in the system bluetooth settings and you should have your DIY Google Home/Amazon Echo up and running! I hope this helps  and have a nice day!

Comment: Its your tablet picking up the ok google. Not the bluetooth device.

Comment: It's the bluetooth hands-free speaker, I've done tests. When it's not connected to the bluetooth speaker it can't hear me unless I'm up close or nearby but when it's connected the the speaker with Bluetooth Headset turned on the Google app settings it can hear me from another room. It didn't work with another speaker I have but it works with my Technika, maybe try a different speaker if you could borrow one as that might be the issue. I hope you get it to work for you, have a good day!

Comment: Pretty sure Google removed this feature so you have to buy a Google Home device... I don't see Ok Google Anywhere (I hear pixels/Nexus still has it?)